# Java: if/then statement and rendering image

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, boolean

So I'm trying to do an if then statement to produce an image if a key is pressed, but if another key is pressed prior to the first key it won't work.  This is the code im trying to use:

```
boolean soil = false;
private void render(){
if(soil = true){
    g.drawImage(soil, 0, 0, Width, Height, this);
if(machine = true && soil = true){
    g.drawImage(machine, 0, 0, Width, Height, this);
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_1){
        soil = true; }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_2){
        machine = true; }
```

why doesn't it draw the image or work?

Comment: where your render method closed?

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons in Java are made with `==`, not `=`. When they are booleans, you don't even need them. See comments below, in code.

```
boolean soil = false;
private void render(){
    if(soil){  // if (soil == true)
        g.drawImage(soil, 0, 0, Width, Height, this);

    if (machine && soil){ // if ( machine == true && soil == true )
        g.drawImage(machine, 0, 0, Width, Height, this);
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_1){
        soil = true; 
    }else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_2) {
        machine = true; 
    }
}
```